# Duplicate and incorrect output sql query

Tags: sql-server

I need to select grade_name from tblgrade, subject_name from tblsubject, count (subscribe_id) from tblsubcription, count (sub_status) from tblsubcription where sub_status=1 and  count (sub_status) from tblsubcription where sub_status is null.

[image: This is the tables I mention]

This is what i have tried:

```sql
SELECT t2.grade_name,
       t.subject_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tblsubcription
        WHERE sub_status IS NULL
          AND teacher_id = 2) AS pending,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tblsubcription
        WHERE sub_status = '1'
          AND teacher_id = 2) AS appoved,
       COUNT(t1.subscribe_id) AS totalsub
FROM tblsubject t
     INNER JOIN tblsubject_grade tg ON (t.subject_id = tg.subject_id)
     INNER JOIN tblsubcription t1 ON (tg.subject_garde_id = t1.subject_garde_id)
     INNER JOIN tblgrade t2 ON (tg.grade_id = t2.grade_id)
                           AND tg.grade_id = t2.grade_id
                           AND tg.subject_id = t.subject_id
                           AND t2.admin_id = t.admin_id
WHERE t1.teacher_id = 2
GROUP BY t.subject_name,
         t2.grade_name;
```

See result obtained when the above query is executed and the expected result i need is in red

[image: See result obtained when the above query is executed and the expected result i need is in red]

Comment: fyi, posting images of code or data here tend to get your posts downvoted or closed. If you want a better chance to get a (faster) answer, find a way to write this with formatted text instead of images.

Comment: Things that make the query harder to read and maintain: 1. prefixing tables with the unnecessary "tbl", 2. aliasing tables as "t1", "t2", etc., 3. misspelled table "subscription".

Comment: Your sub queries aren't correlated, so of course they are going to return the same value on all rows. So, for example, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblsubcription WHERE sub_status IS NULL AND teacher_id = 2` is always going to return `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this subquery:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM tblsubcription
 WHERE sub_status IS NULL
     AND teacher_id = 2) AS pending,
```

There is nothing here to relate (correlate) it to the specific row. You need an additional condition in the `WHERE` clause that tells you which Grade/Subject pair to look at. The other (approved) subquery is the same way.

Alternatively, you may be able to solve this with another join to `tblsubscription` and [conditional aggregation](https://riptutorial.com/sql/example/3419/conditional-aggregation).

I'd post code to fix this, but I find the images too blurry to read well, so I can't easily infer which fields to use. Next time post formatted text, and you'll get a better answer in less time.

Comment: i have edited the post please have a look.